# how much energy efficiency is there when photons converted to positrons?

Tags: photons

actually i am participating in NASA ames space settlement and want to transmit electricity through antimatter. i had created the photon by using the carbon dioxide, nitrogen, helium and hydrogen. i am not able to find how much is the efficiency of energy when photon converted to positrons? please do reply

Comment: What is the purpose of using positrons instead of electrons for your electrical transmission?

Answer (score 1):

Your overall efficiency will be well less than 50%. There are several factors at play here:

To generate a positron with photons, you also have to generate an electron in order for the quantum symmetry to be preserved. When you generate a pair this way, they end up with half the energy each. If you are only using one of those for your transmission vessel, then you are discarding half of your original energy right there, not counting all the photons you generate that don't create particle pairs to begin with.

Then you have to run the equipment that generates the positrons in the first place, which is likely to be a large machine that takes a lot of power to run, and not necessarily very efficient itself.

Then, since you're using antimatter charge carriers, your cables also have to be made of antimatter, and you'll need some kind of vacuum system to keep air/dust/soil/etc. from annihilating it, so that's more expensive and inefficient equipment.

By the time you get to the application of the electricity (positricity?) you've spent a lot of energy on creating and maintaining an antimatter power grid that behaves exactly like a left-handed normal electrical system. The exact efficiency depends on systems engineering but there's no way to have a positron-based energy transfer that nearly compares to regular methods.